# Angular 8 - change the API URL to a local server for login authentication

Tags: angular, jwt, local-storage, angular8, angular-local-storage

I am currently following a tutorial from https://thinkster.io/tutorials/building-real-world-angular-2-apps/intercept-and-manipulate-http-requests to create an Angular 8 application in which Users can sign-up, create posts, view global posts, like posts, and follow other users.

The tutorial provides a live API server running at https://conduit.productionready.io/api for the application to make requests against - this provides the application with posts from other users who are using the tutorial. Here is the link to the github with the repo I clones and customized: https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app#making-requests-to-the-backend-api

However, **I want to use my own local server (localStorage?) to test my app & create the users & posts myself.  Later I will wire this API to communicate with my Java/Spring code and PostgreSQL database.**

This is what my `environment.ts` file looks like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_url: 'https://conduit.productionready.io/api'
};
```

And this is what my `api.service.ts` file looks like:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
    import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable ,  throwError } from 'rxjs';

    import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable()
    export class ApiService {
      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private jwtService: JwtService
      ) {}

      private formatErrors(error: any) {
        return  throwError(error.error);
      }

      get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { params })
          .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
      }

      put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(
          `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
          JSON.stringify(body)
        ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
      }

      post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(
          `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
          JSON.stringify(body)
        ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
      }

      delete(path): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete(
          `${environment.api_url}${path}`
        ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
      }
    }
```

And, Just incase, here is my `user.service.ts` file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable ,  BehaviorSubject ,  ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';
import { User } from '../models';
import { map ,  distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);
  public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  private isAuthenticatedSubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  public isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();

  constructor (
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private jwtService: JwtService
  ) {}

  // Verify JWT in localstorage with server & load user's info.
  // This runs once on application startup.
  populate() {
    // If JWT detected, attempt to get & store user's info
    if (this.jwtService.getToken()) {
      this.apiService.get('/user')
      .subscribe(
        data => this.setAuth(data.user),
        err => this.purgeAuth()
      );
    } else {
      // Remove any potential remnants of previous auth states
      this.purgeAuth();
    }
  }

  setAuth(user: User) {
    // Save JWT sent from server in localstorage
    this.jwtService.saveToken(user.token);
    // Set current user data into observable
    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
    // Set isAuthenticated to true
    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
  }

  purgeAuth() {
    // Remove JWT from localstorage
    this.jwtService.destroyToken();
    // Set current user to an empty object
    this.currentUserSubject.next({} as User);
    // Set auth status to false
    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
  }

  attemptAuth(type, credentials): Observable<User> {
    const route = (type === 'login') ? '/login' : '';
    return this.apiService.post('/users' + route, {user: credentials})
      .pipe(map(
      data => {
        this.setAuth(data.user);
        return data;
      }
    ));
  }

  getCurrentUser(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  // Update the user on the server (email, pass, etc)
  update(user): Observable<User> {
    return this.apiService
    .put('/user', { user })
    .pipe(map(data => {
      // Update the currentUser observable
      this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);
      return data.user;
    }));
  }

}
```

The instructions in the README.md say:

> If you want to change the API URL to a local server, simply edit
>   src/environments/environment.ts and change api_url to the local
>   server's URL (i.e. localhost:3000/api)

But when I do this (change `api_url:` in `environment.ts` to `'http://localhost:4200/api'`), and try to create an account, the page does not react, and I get this message in the console when I inspect:

> POST http://localhost:4200/api/users 404 (Not Found)

How can I change this so that I can create and store users with localStorage?

Comment: the port `4200` is used for the basic web server that run your angular App while `ng serve`-ing. do you have any web server running for your API, currently ?

Comment: LocalStorage lives in the browser directly, it's not a server to reach. You don't store things in the browser's LocalStorage by calling a server. You just go `localStorage.setItem("itemname", data)`

Comment: @JeremyThille, so, hypothetically if I start up a postgreSQL database, run it on Tomcat Server at port 8080, and then set api_url: http://localhost:8080, would it store the users in my postgres tables?

Comment: I don't know, I've never done that. I've never used Tomcat or Postgre, but if I transpose it to Mongo + Node, yes, I guess so

Comment: Postgresql is not a no-sql server, like mongo is, which mean you need to do some SQL statement to add data to it. If the server running on 8080 is not design to receive data and create SQL statement that would enter data in the DB ( like a REST API ) it won't work.

Comment: @Nicolas Say I don't have any database set up - I'm assuiming that with Postman I could create a mock server and API, correct?  Could I then simply replace the `api_url`  in my `environment.ts` with the API that I fake from Postman, thus replacing `'https://conduit.productionready.io/api'`?

Comment: You could mock a server with postman but i'm not sure how it work. You'd be better off trying to build an API first and then connect it to your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

we have 2 environment files 
1. environment.ts (development) http://localhost:8000 where 8000 is port of your local server

2. environment.prod.ts (deployment) http://***.**.**.**:8080/AnalyticsServer-1.0 where replace * with your IP and 8080 is port of server (tomcat) and AnalyticsServer-1.0 is the name of deployed war file